# How to skip empty data frame in a loop and save a combined result

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have excel files that have three identical tabs. I looped through all excel files in a directory and created a separated data frame for each tab. After I did some cleaning on each data frame, I combined the three data frame into one and saved into a new sheet.

In general, my code works but it returns an error when one(or more) of the tabs in the excels are empty.

For example, each excel file has three tabs: data1, data2, and data3 and I read each tab into a separate data frame: df_1, df_2, and df_3. However, some files only have some of the three tabs, not all of them and I think my code breaks in that case.

How do I update my code to resolve this issue? I want to check whether a tab is empty or not and import it if it's not empty. At the end, I'd still like to combine all data frames. For example if an excel file only has data1 and data3 tabs, the final data frame will be df_1 + df_3.

```
datapath = r"C:\Users\Documents\sample"
excel_files = glob.glob(datapath + '*.xlsx')

for excel in excel_files:
    df_1 = pd.read_excel(excel, sheet_name="data1", header=None)
    df_2 = pd.read_excel(excel, sheet_name="data2", header=None)
    df_3 = pd.read_excel(excel, sheet_name="data3", header=None)

    df_1.rename(columns={0:'ID_Num'}, inplace = True)
    df_1 = df_bon.groupby(["ID_Num"]).size().reset_index(name='Count')
    df_1['Name'] = df_bon['ID_Num'].str[:3]

    df_2.rename(columns={0:'ID_Num'}, inplace = True)
    df_2 = df_2.groupby(["ID_Num"]).size().reset_index(name='Count')
    df_2['Name'] = df_2['ID_Num'].str[:3]


    df_3.rename(columns={0:'ID_Num'}, inplace = True)
    df_3 = df_3.groupby(["ID_Num"]).size().reset_index(name='Count')
    df_3['Name'] = df_3['ID_Num'].str[:3]
    
    df_final = df_1.append([df_2, df_3],ignore_index=True)
    
 
    df_final.to_excel(excel, sheet_name="New Data")
```

Comment: [`df_final.dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)? It will remove rows that contain any null (NaN) values.

Comment: rewrite your inner copy-paste code into a second for-loop. then use if-else to either add a df or skip.

Comment: check out using sheet_name=None. It'll read all sheets that exist and put the dataframes into a list. You should be able to concatenate them and not have to worry about missing sheets https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: can't edit my original answer. the response is a dictionary of dfs. you can do this pd.concat(df.values()).reset_index() and do the name changes and grouping on the final dataframe. if you can't do that on final df, you an loop through values() and then concat.